# Get current user in desktop file (GNOME)

Tags: gnome, desktop, menu

To run applications from [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome), users *click* on icons on their desktops or they select the applications which they want to run from a menu.

I'm looking for a **valid replacement pattern**, to get the **current user** within a [desktop file](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FooCorp Painter Pro
Exec=/run/media/%%USER_NAME%%/foocorp-usb-stick/foocorp-painter-pro
Icon=foocorp-painter-pro
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
```

Comment: [There is none.](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can not add some ENV variable in Desktop file but you can achieve what you want by creating the same desktop file in every user's home directory.

Path is as:

`~/.local/share/applications/`

These desktop files are user-specific. 
You can even add desktop-directories too, if desired.